# cucumber: how to run a tagged scenario from a specific feature file

Tags: java, cucumber

I have the following cucumber feature:

```
Feature: Myfeature

@tag1
Scenario: 1st scenario
  Given 
  When 
  Then 

@tag2
Scenario: 2nd scenario
  Given  
  When 
  Then
```

I want to run ONLY the tagged scenario @tag1 from Myfeature file and ignore @tag1 from others features files

I tried the following command but it is not working as expected

```
 mvn verify -P nrt -Denv=Dev 
 -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/scenarios/MyFeature.feature --tags @tag1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cucumber.options` property was deprecated and removed. You have to pass each option as a single property.

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags='@smoke and not @ignore' -Dcucumber.features=path/to.feature
```

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/core/README.md
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v5.0.0.md#property-based-options

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try simple workaround and add one more tag that is unique like **@tag1Myfeature**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "AND" condition in your CucumberRunner Options -> tags
tags = {“@Feature”, “@tag1”} : means AND condition. –It says that scenarios matching both these tag needs to be executed.